# Command to Xcopy folders across the network and rename the folder at destination as the date

Tags: windows, file-transfer, cmd.exe, xcopy

I'm using Xcopy to copy a folder across a network

> *XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\File\Output*.*" "C:\new" /s /e /c

I want the folder at the destination to be named with the date. E.G .\19-10-2013
How do i go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\File\Output*." "C:\new\%date%\" /s /e /c
```

This will create a directory with the format of your date. But when sorting the directories by name they will not be sorted by date. I would transform 19-06-2013 to 2013-06-19.

If you want a directory like YYYY-MM-DD you could do it like this:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%I IN (`echo %date%`) do set mydate=%%K-%%J-%%I
XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\File\Output*." "C:\new\%mydate%\" /s /e /c
pause
```

If your date format (and separator) is different you need to fiddle a bit to get it right.
(if you need help with that let us know your date format.)

Comment: Thanks man. I've used the first one sucessfully. i'm actually creating a job in MSSQL 03 that will run that. it's working via command prompt but timing out as a job. i'll troubleshoot that though.

Comment: Reading this article may help with the renaming of destination "File Names" rather "Folder Names" if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255574/1830909